# How to define a (internal) task without having it listed it in "grunt --help"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am defining my tasks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('tmp', 'An internal task', [
    'clean:tmp',
    'jshint',
    'ember_templates',
    'neuter',
    'copy:tmp',
    'replace:tmp',
]);
```

since this is a task which is not supposed to be called by the user, I would like to avoid showing it with `grunt --help`. Is this possible?

I have not found any related config parameter in the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Creating-tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see in the grunt-code for the help task this code which [loops over an array of all tasks - currently starts at line 106](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/help.js#L106)

```
exports.tasks = function() {
  grunt.log.header('Available tasks');
  if (exports._tasks.length === 0) {
    grunt.log.writeln('(no tasks found)');
  } else {
     exports.table(exports._tasks.map(function(task) {
       var info = task.info;
       if (task.multi) { info += ' *'; }
       return [task.name, info];
     }));
  ...
```

this means we should take a look where this [array is filled - (currently starts at line 94)](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/help.js#L94):

```
exports.initTasks = function() {
  // Initialize task system so that the tasks can be listed.
  grunt.task.init([], {help: true});

  // Build object of tasks by info (where they were loaded from).
  exports._tasks = [];
  Object.keys(grunt.task._tasks).forEach(function(name) {
    exports.initCol1(name);
    var task = grunt.task._tasks[name];
    exports._tasks.push(task);
  });
};
```

here you can see, that there is a loop over all registered tasks (the object grunt.task._tasks). inside the loop there is no check, so now must see where this object is filled.

and this is done in the [registerTask-prototype-method (currently line 78)](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/util/task.js#L78):

```
// Register a new task.
Task.prototype.registerTask = function(name, info, fn) {

    ... some other code

    // Add task into cache.
    this._tasks[name] = {name: name, info: info, fn: fn};
```

now that means a clear NO for your question. you can not register a task which will not be shown on --help.

but there is an [issue filed on the grunt github repository](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/741) for exactly your problem (private tasks). feel free to fork the repository, make that work and give it back to the community ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider doing that (my javascript is limited)